# How to build an SDK for my application that has multiple technology module

Tags: python, android, plugins, sdk, chatbot

I have a chatbot application that has backend modules coded in Java, AI features implemented with Python coding and frontend in ReactJs. My problem statement is:

The chatbot is such that it can be placed onto websites, but now I need to find a solution, how can I install this chatbot in an android app/iOS app? Perhaps, it is through an SDK.

I searched over multiple places but couldn't find an answer to how can I build an SDK including all these modules of different coding languages under one structure? Each of the modules have their own dependencies and not that the same module has been coded in a different language.

Need help here.